# Php Laravel - How to show xml file in browser

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I produced xml file in my directory. I want to show this file in browser using php?

(I want to show that as sitemap)

Here is my code :

```
   public function siteMap()
    {
        $test_array = array (
            'bla' => 'blub',
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'another_array' => array (
                'stack' => 'overflow',
            ),
        );

        $xml_template_info = new \SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><template></template>");

        $this->array_to_xml($test_array,$xml_template_info);
        $xml_template_info->asXML(dirname(__FILE__)."/sitemap.xml") ;
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        dd(readfile(dirname(__FILE__)."/sitemap.xml"));
    }

    public function array_to_xml(array $arr, \SimpleXMLElement $xml)
    {
      foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
          is_array($v)
              ? $this->array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k))
              : $xml->addChild($k, $v);
      }
      return $xml;
   }
```

And here is **sitemap.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template><bla>blub</bla><foo>bar</foo><another_array><stack>overflow</stack></another_array></template>
```

Here is result :
[image]

I want show this xml file in my browser, Any idea for doing this correctly?

**EDITED :** Here is result with **header('Content-type: text/plain');**
[image]

It consist of some extra reports.

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: I think `header('Content-type: text/plain');` should work!

Comment: @Alok I added to my question.

Comment: @BenHillier I added it's result to my question.

Comment: That error is telling you exactly what's wrong with the output. There's a lot of extra content after the `</template>` tag is closed. Nothing will display it as XML, because it's not valid XML. Something is sending the extra data! Perhaps try an `exit();` after the `readfile` call.

Comment: @BenHillier Put it as answer.

Comment: @afn: Sure. Has been added.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the content of xml is in $xml variable, you can use one of the followings:

```
return response($xml, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

OR

```
return response($xml, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/xml']);
```

Answer (score 6):

In your view create sitemap.blade.php. 
Insert content xml in your sitemap.blade.php. 
Create a function called sistemap.

```
 public function sitemap(){

     return response()->view('sitemap')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

 }
```

In your routes:

```
 Route::get('sitemap', function () {
     return view('sitemap');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/sitemap.xml', function (Request $request) {
     return response()->view('sitemap')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php

public function array_to_xml(array $data, \SimpleXMLElement $xml) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                $key = 'item' . $key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
            }
            $subnode = $xml->addChild($key);
            $this->array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml->addChild("$key", htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}

public function siteMap()
    {
$data = array(
        'bla' => 'blub',
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'another_array' => array(
            'stack' => 'overflow',
        ),
    );

    $xml_template_info = new \SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><template></template>");
    $this->array_to_xml($data, $xml_template_info);
    $xml_template_info->asXML(dirname(__FILE__) . "/sitemap.xml");
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    die(readfile(dirname(__FILE__) . "/sitemap.xml"));
//or return readfile(dirname(__FILE__) . "/sitemap.xml");
    }
```

Comment: I'm coding in Laravel so I must use  $this->array_to_xml($test_array, $xml_template_info);

Comment: So implement that function to your method in Laravel, you not give body of your method so I add simple one function.

Comment: I did it , when we use die() , it shows me proper result. but is there any way to return it's result as xml?

Comment: Also , FILE is undefined constant so when I put __FILE__ i get 127.

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you exactly what's wrong with the output. There's a lot of extra content after the `</template>` tag is closed. Nothing will display it as XML, because it's not valid XML. Something is sending the extra data!

Perhaps try an `exit();` after the `readfile` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just show the contents of an xml file in browser same way as they look in xml file,just write `name_of_xml_file.xml` in url after the base address.

For example:

> www.example.com/**name_of_xml_file.xml**

regardless of where you place it.

It should be in your websites folder and just use a function to redirect to that page if you want to autoload when a certain thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add the xml file in the public folder of Laravel. Something like sitemap.xml. So you can easily access it with `http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's `dd` function outputs a bunch of HTML to let you browse the debugging input. It's intended for debugging, **not** outputting normal stuff to the page. You shouldn't be using it like this.

Instead of

```
dd(readfile(dirname(__FILE__)."/sitemap.xml"));
```

try

```
return readfile(dirname(__FILE__)."/sitemap.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a Laravel xml response package: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml

Install that and it's as simple as:

```
$test_array = array (
        'bla' => 'blub',
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'another_array' => array (
            'stack' => 'overflow',
        ),
    );
return response()->xml($test_array, 200, [], 'template');
```

And you get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template>
    <bla>blub</bla>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <another_array>
        <stack>overflow</stack>
    </another_array>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a route:

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml', 'SitemapController@index')->name('sitemapxml');
```

Put this code in your controller:

```
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::where('status', '=', 1)->get();
    return response()->view('sitemap_xml', ['posts' => $posts])->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

Put this code in your view file:

```
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <url>
            <loc>{{ url($post->url) }}</loc>
            <lastmod>{{ $post->updated_at->tz('UTC')->toAtomString() }}</lastmod>
            <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
            <priority>0.7</priority>
        </url>
    @endforeach
</urlset>
```